# Emition Bake is partly too dark

Tags: materials

So, I was trying to bake an albedo map with emission shader and for some reason, some part of the texture is always too dark. It's not the normals, I flipped them many times, tried different texture sizes, used a different UV map and practically tried every trick in the book to make it work.

**Here is the render from emission shader + bake**
[image: Here is the render from emission shader + bake]

**And here the applied material**
[image: And here the applied material]

Please can someone help? I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution which works for me. I tried to bake an albedo together with the ao-node. Part of it doesn't show correctly on the texture...
AO Bake didn't solve the problem either, so I baked an ao-texture as an emission texture which solved my problem.

[image]Still don't know why blender did this or what went wrong, but it did work for me